# Windows Experience Index could not be computed - disk assessment fails

Tags: windows-7, windows-experience-index

When trying to rate my system's performance with the Windows Experience Index, I get an error:

> The Windows Experience Index for your system could not be computed. Could not measure storage performance. Error: Failed to properly assess the disk. The data is invalid.

How do I work around this? I suspect it might be related to the use of Intel's Rapid Storage technology to RAID10 the drives.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this so far? Googling your error brings up quite a few possible solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was solved by:

- Open Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings
- Click the Advanced Tab
- Click the "Environment Variables..." button at the bottom
- The local user variables for TEMP and TMP use paths that include %USERPROFILE%. Replace this with a hard link, e.g. `D:\User\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp`.